# Terminal having problems with whitespace of some operation

Tags: macos, terminal, whitespace, zsh, iterm

After some operation in console I am having problems with whitespace that looks like this:

[image: http://monosnap.com/image/ZgJcTzp7iTGfqVLyl1Ex7bQmSSLSr1.png]

Any command at some point starts to having issues with whitespace. Even `ls`.

Here is the $TERM output:

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
              %
$
```

Is it possible to prevent such issues?

Is it possible to reset current terminal and adjust whitespace to normal level?

Software: zsh, osx, iTerm

Comment: Possibly an issue with your `TERM` setting? It looks like each line is ending only with a line feed, not a carriage return as well. (Each line starts in the column after the one the previous line ends in.) What does `echo $TERM` output?

Comment: Is the problem only with `gst`, or is it in any command that follows the `zt` command?

Comment: Updated questions with this info.

Comment: Try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Looks like the problem with termcap/terminfo varibles. Does command `reset` help?

Comment: Yes, `reset` helped. Thanks. You can create an answer and I'll accept it. Maybe there is better solution that will prevent this problem from appearing.